# Custom iterator class, list iterators incompatible

Tags: c++, list, iterator

Hi I'm trying to make a program that will list all permutations of a list of strings. I am trying to implement a custom iterator that will automatically loop the iterator back to the beginning/end. I get a "list iterators incompatible" error in the subIt function, more specifically

```
if (myIt == tempList.begin())
                myIt = tempList.end();
```

Iterator Class:

```
class MyIterator : public iterator<bidirectional_iterator_tag, list<string>>
{
public:

    MyIterator operator=(const list<string>::iterator x) { this->myIt = x; return *this; }
    void addIt(int x, list<string> tempList)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= x; i++)
        {
            myIt++;
            if (myIt == tempList.end())
                myIt = tempList.begin();
        }
    }
    void subIt(int x, list<string> tempList)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= x; i++)
        {
            if (myIt == tempList.begin())
                myIt = tempList.end();
            myIt--;
        }
    }
    string getIt() { return *myIt; }
private:
    list<string>::iterator myIt;
};
```

Function that calls subIt and addIt

```
list<string> generate_permutations(list<string> temp)
{
    list<string> permutations;
    int size = temp.size();
    int i;
    int j;
    MyIterator it1;
    MyIterator it2;
    for (auto eachString : temp)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
        {
            permutations.push_back(eachString);
            it1 = permutations.end();
            it1.subIt(1, permutations);
            it1.getIt().push_back(' ');
        }
    }
    for (int x = 0; x < size; x++)
    {
        it1 = permutations.begin();
        for (j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            it2 = temp.begin();

            for (i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
            {
                (it1.getIt()).append(it2.getIt());
                (it1.getIt()).push_back(' ');
                it1.addIt(1, permutations);
                it2.addIt(1, temp);
            }
        }
    }
    return permutations;
}
```

I have a plan for how the function will work, I only really need help with the iterators.

Comment: exactly what error are you getting please paste the text of it

Comment: you can only compare iterators referring to the same container. `list<string> tempList` cannot possibly be the same container as the one that spawned `myIt` because `templist` is a copy that only exists inside the `addIt` and `subIt` functions. Some pass by reference might be needed, but it's still iffy as the functions could be called with any `list<string>`.

Comment: you need to be passing that list in by reference

Comment: @user4581301 Thank you, that's eliminated the error.